# Android Intent not calling class

Tags: android, android-intent

My Code here is calling my class Round List, but when i click "Round 1" Button, nothing happens, i do not get any errors, it just does not work, if someone has any idea why this is occurring could you please let me know, Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public LinearLayout layout;
public LinearLayout roundList;
private Button round1, round2, round3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
    setContentView(scroll);

    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scroll.addView(layout);

    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setText("Select Round");
    title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40);
    title.setPadding(6,6,6,6);
    title.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 150, 0));
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    layout.addView(title);

    roundList = new LinearLayout(this);
    roundList.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.addView(roundList);

    Button round1 = new Button(this);       
    round1.setText("Round 1");
    round1.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
    round1.setOnClickListener(this);
    layout.addView(round1);

    Button round2 = new Button(this);
    round2.setText("Round 2");
    round2.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
    round2.setOnClickListener(this);
    layout.addView(round2);

    Button round3 = new Button(this);
    round3.setText("Round 3");
    round3.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
    round3.setOnClickListener(this);
    layout.addView(round3);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == round1) {
        Intent round = new Intent(this, RoundList.class);
        startActivity(round);
    }
}//end onClick
```

}

This is my RoundList class.

```
public class RoundList extends MainActivity implements RoundCallback {

public RoundList() {

    TextView subTitle = new TextView(this);
    subTitle.setText("Results");
    subTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40);
    subTitle.setPadding(6,6,6,6);
    subTitle.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 150, 0));
    subTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    layout.addView(subTitle);

    new GetRound(this);
}

public void addMatchup(JSONObject matchup) throws JSONException {
    LinearLayout laid = new LinearLayout(this);
    laid.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    laid.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 20);

    LinearLayout teams = new LinearLayout(this);
    teams.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    //teams.setWeightSum(1.0f);

    LinearLayout teamHome = new LinearLayout(this);
    teamHome.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    teamHome.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            0.4f));

    TextView teamHomeName = new TextView(this);
    final String teamHomeStr = matchup.getJSONObject("teamHome").getString("name");
    teamHomeName.setText(teamHomeStr);
    teamHomeName.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    teamHomeName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    teamHome.addView(teamHomeName);

    TextView teamHomeScore = new TextView(this);
    teamHomeScore.setText(matchup.getJSONObject("result").getString("home"));
    teamHomeScore.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    teamHomeScore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    teamHome.addView(teamHomeScore);

    teams.addView(teamHome);

    TextView vs = new TextView(this);
    vs.setText("vs");
    vs.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    vs.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    vs.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            0.65f));
    vs.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //vs.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    teams.addView(vs);


    LinearLayout teamAway = new LinearLayout(this);
    teamAway.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    teamAway.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            0.4f));

    TextView teamAwayName = new TextView(this);
    final String teamAwayStr = matchup.getJSONObject("teamAway").getString("name");
    teamAwayName.setText(teamAwayStr);
    teamAwayName.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    teamAwayName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    teamAway.addView(teamAwayName);

    TextView teamAwayScore = new TextView(this);
    teamAwayScore.setText(matchup.getJSONObject("result").getString("away"));
    teamAwayScore.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    teamAwayScore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    teamAway.addView(teamAwayScore);

    teams.addView(teamAway);

    laid.addView(teams);

    final String locationStr = matchup.getString("location");
    TextView location = new TextView(this);
    location.setText(locationStr);
    location.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    location.setPadding(0,0,0,6);
    location.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    location.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    location.setClickable(true);
    location.setOnClickListener(this);
    laid.addView(location);

    final String timeStr = matchup.getString("time");       
    TextView time = new TextView(this);
    time.setText(timeStr);
    time.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    time.setPadding(0,6,0,0);
    time.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    time.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    time.setClickable(true);
    time.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
        @Override
        //Sends an appointment fixture to a calender
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            beginTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30);
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 8, 30);

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = formatter.parse(timeStr);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            long dateInLong = date.getTime();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                    .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, dateInLong)
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, dateInLong + 1000 * 60 * 60)
                    .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Soccer match")
                    .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Soccer match between " 
                    + teamHomeStr + " and " + teamAwayStr)
                    .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, locationStr)
                    .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
                    ;
            startActivity(intent);
        }});
    laid.addView(time);

    roundList.addView(laid);

    //get sms details and output to sms application
    TextView sms = new TextView(this);
    sms.setText("SMS Details");
    sms.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    sms.setPadding(0,6,0,0);
    sms.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    sms.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    sms.setClickable(true);
    sms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String uri= "smsto:";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", "\"" + teamHomeStr + " vs " + teamAwayStr + "\n" + locationStr + "\n" + timeStr + "\"");
        intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
        startActivity(intent);
        }});
    laid.addView(sms);
}

@Override
public void roundCallback(JSONObject obj) {
    JSONArray matchups;
    try {
        matchups = obj.getJSONArray("matchups");

        for (int i = 0; i < matchups.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject matchup = matchups.getJSONObject(i);

            addMatchup(matchup);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
//Locates the location using Google maps.
public void onClick(View obj) {
    if (obj instanceof TextView) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) obj;
        String uri = "geo:0,0?q=" + txt.getText().toString().replace(' ', '+');
        startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code should be

```
round1 = new Button(this);
round2 = new Button(this);
round3 = new Button(this);
```

and not

```
Button round1 = new Button(this);
Button round2 = new Button(this);
Button round3 = new Button(this);
```

in your code you are hiding the memember class `round1`, `round2`, `round3` ridefining those in the scope of the `onCreate` method

Comment: I see. Why does RoundClass extends MainActivity and not Activity?

Comment: then inside RoundClass you should override onCreate, and so on

Comment: yeah the duplicate methods has @override now

Comment: "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.edsl/com.example.edsl.RoundList}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?" This is error i am receiving when i click my button, sorry I am new to android.

Comment: Have you declared the RoundList class inside you AndroidManifest? That`s mandatory for all activities

Comment: """<activity
            android:name="com.example.edsl.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>""" This is the one correct? its there or am i missing something in there?

Comment: Nevermind i declared it, Thank you so much for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The reason another activity is not started when you click the button is because the button you are checking in `OnClick()` method is `never clicked`.

You are creating a `local button object round1 in OnCreate()` method instead of instantiating the `round1` button object which is visible to whole class. So when the OnCreate() method goes out of scope, the local button object is also destroyed and collected by garbage collector.

To solve this problem,j ust remove `Button` before `round1,round2, round3 in OnCreate()` method and your problem should be solved.